# Yanking after `isearch-forward/backward`

Tags: isearch, yank

When doing a `yank` after an `isearch-forward/backward`, the most natural thing that one wishes to happen is to isearch the string provided by that yank. How to realize this?

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you mean? It's already the case that if you `C-s C-y`, it'll yank text into the minibuffer, and isearch will search the text in the buffer for the yanked text.

Comment: Are you sure? For me I have to press `C-y` two times to achieve this (i.e. `C-s C-y C-y`). But the natural thing is to press `C-s C-y` as you said. I have the impression that it is because when doing `C-s` the minibuffer is not in focus.

Comment: Yeah, `C-s C-y` definitely works for me. I'm using Emacs 24.4; how about you? Does it also not work starting from `emacs -Q`?

Comment: As @zck suggested, the default behavior should already be as you describe. `C-s` prompts for the search string; `C-y` yanks the most recent kill in to that prompt and since it is an incremental search it immediately moves to the first match. If you aren't seeing this, perhaps try starting `emacs -Q` to make sure some other configuration is not overriding the default behavior?

Comment: Yes, actually it works when starting from `emacs -Q`.

Comment: Recently I have installed the packages `isearch+` when I remove the line `(require 'isearch+)` from my init file, the problem is solved. Thanks zck and glucas for your help. I guess I should delete this question.

Comment: @Name Search for what `C-y` is bound to in the `isearch-mode-map` by `isearch+`. Keeping this question might be useful for people facing the same confusion. You can answer your own question.

Comment: Check that package's documentation in its header; by design you need to hit `C-y C-y` to do the usual `yank`: ``;; `C-y C-y'    `isearch-yank-kill'``.

Comment: @drew So for your comment is the most informative addressing the problem raised in this question . So if you think this can help other people facing the same question and it is worth to keep this question (as pointed out by kaushalmodi), please consider to convert your comments as an answer in order that I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: OK, I posted the info here as an answer, and deleted it from the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say:

> *Recently I have installed the packages isearch+ when I remove the line `(require 'isearch+)` from my init file, the problem is solved.*

@kaushalmodi said:

> Search for what `C-y` is bound to in the `isearch-mode-map` by isearch+.

and

> Check that package's documentation in its header; by design you need to hit `C-y C-y` to do the usual yank:
>
> ;; `C-y C-y` `isearch-yank-kill`.

By default, `C-y` is a prefix key in [**Isearch+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus). There are multiple yank commands, all bound to keys on prefix `C-y`. `C-y C-y` is bound by default to `isearch-yank-kill`.

You can of course bind any key you like (in `isearch-mode-map`) to any Isearch command, including to `isearch-yank-kill`:

```el
(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "WHATEVER") 'isearch-yank-kill)
```

FYI -- You can not only get this info from the [**isearch+.el**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/isearch%2b.el) library file header, as @kaushalmodi pointed out. You can also use `C-s C-h` to see all bindings in the Isearch-mode keymap. And if you use library [**help-fns+.el**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/help-fns%2b.el) then you can also use `C-h M-k isearch-mode-map` to see a human-readable description of all of the keys and their commands.